# WebApi + OData = Error -> "The property does not belong to the specified type"

Tags: .net-4.0, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, odata

Any OData command that I use in my URIs, the following error is shown!
When I use the api without any configuration/parameter OData, works perfectly!
But any `$filter`, `$top` or `$skip`, generates the error below:

## Code

**ApiController**

```
[Queryable]
public IQueryable<Processo> get()
{
    return _repositorio.Query<Processo>();
}
```

**Api Routes**

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
{
    // Controller Only -> To handle routes like `/api/pessoas`
    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "ControllerOnly",
        routeTemplate: "api/{controller}"
    );

    // Controller with ID -> To handle routes like `/api/pessoas/1`
    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "ControllerAndId",
        routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
        defaults: null,
        constraints: new { id = @"^\d+$" } // Only integers 
    );

    // Controllers with Actions -> To handle routes like `/api/pessoas/getProfissoes`
    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "ControllerAndAction",
        routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}"
    );

    config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.PreserveReferencesHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.PreserveReferencesHandling.Objects;
    config.Formatters.Remove(config.Formatters.XmlFormatter);
}
```

**IRepository Query implement**

```
public IQueryable<T> Query<T>(params Expression<Func<T, object>>[] includeProperties)
    where T : class, IEntity
{
    return includeProperties.Aggregate<Expression<Func<T, object>>, IQueryable<T>>(Set<T>(), (current, includeProperty) => current.Include(includeProperty));
}
```

**[Added] Processo class**

```
public class Processo : IEntity, IAuditable
{
    public DateTime CreateAt { get; set; }
    public string CreateBy { get; set; }
    public DateTime? UpdateAt { get; set; }
    public string UpdateBy { get; set; }

    public int Id { get; set; }

    public DateTime DataEntrada { get; set; }
    public virtual Modalidade Modalidade { get; set; }
    public virtual PassoExecucao PassoAtual { get; set; }

    public string Imovel { get; set; }
    public double ValorFinanciado { get; set; }
    public double ValorVenda { get; set; }
    public double? FGTS { get; set; }

    public virtual Pessoa Comprador { get; set; }
    public virtual Pessoa Proprietario { get; set; }

    public virtual Agencia Agencia { get; set; }
    public virtual Empresa Despachante { get; set; }
    public virtual Empresa Originador { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<File> Arquivos { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Historico> Historicos { get; set; }
}
```

## Attempts

1. URL: `/api/processos?$filter=Id eq 1` **Same error**
2. URL: `/api/processos?$skip=1` **Same error**
3. URL: `/api/processos` **NO ERROR!!**

**[Added] Doing some tests. found that only occurs where there is reference to the Person class.**

```
public class Pessoa : IEntity, IAuditable
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public DateTime CreateAt { get; set; }
    public string CreateBy { get; set; }
    public DateTime? UpdateAt { get; set; }
    public string UpdateBy { get; set; }

    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DataNascimento { get; set; }
    public GeneroEnum Genero { get; set; }
    public virtual TipoPessoa Tipo { get; set; }
    public virtual Pessoa Conjuge { get; set; }

    public virtual Nacionalidade Nacionalidade { get; set; }
    public string Naturalidade { get; set; }
    public virtual Profissao Profissao { get; set; }
    public string Empresa { get; set; }
    public double? RendaBrutaMensal { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DataInicioEmpresa { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DataReferenciaEmpresa { get; set; }
    public EscolaridadeEnum Escolaridade { get; set; }

    public string CPF { get; set; }
    public string PIS { get; set; }
    public string RG { get; set; }
    public string OrgaoExpedidor { get; set; }
    public string TipoDocumento { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DataEmissao { get; set; }

    public EstadoCivilEnum? EstadoCivil { get; set; }
    public RegimeCasamentoEnum? RegimeCasamento { get; set; }
    public bool? ComposicaoRenda { get; set; }
    public bool? UniaoEstavel { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Telefone> Telefones { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Endereco> Enderecos { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Email> Emails { get; set; }
}
```

## Error

**With Processo class**

```
[Queryable]
public IQueryable<Processo> get()
{
    return _repositorio.Query<Processo>();
}
```

[image]

```
{
    "$id": "1",
    "Message": "An error has occurred.",
    "ExceptionMessage": "The property does not belong to the specified type.\r\nParameter name: navigationProperty",
    "ExceptionType": "System.ArgumentException",
    "StackTrace": "   at System.Web.Http.OData.Builder.EntityTypeConfiguration.AddNavigationProperty(PropertyInfo navigationProperty, EdmMultiplicity multiplicity)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.OData.Builder.ODataConventionModelBuilder.MapEntityType(IEntityTypeConfiguration entity)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.OData.Builder.ODataConventionModelBuilder.AddEntity(Type type)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.OData.Builder.EntityTypeConfiguration.AddNavigationProperty(PropertyInfo navigationProperty, EdmMultiplicity multiplicity)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.OData.Builder.ODataConventionModelBuilder.MapEntityType(IEntityTypeConfiguration entity)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.OData.Builder.ODataConventionModelBuilder.MapTypes()\r\n   at System.Web.Http.OData.Builder.ODataConventionModelBuilder.GetEdmModel()\r\n   at System.Web.Http.HttpActionDescriptorExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass1.<GetEdmModel>b__0(Object _)\r\n   at System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary`2.GetOrAdd(TKey key, Func`2 valueFactory)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.HttpActionDescriptorExtensions.GetEdmModel(HttpActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, Type entityClrType)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.QueryableAttribute.OnActionExecuted(HttpActionExecutedContext actionExecutedContext)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.CallOnActionExecuted(HttpActionContext actionContext, HttpResponseMessage response, Exception exception)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.<>c__DisplayClass2.<System.Web.Http.Filters.IActionFilter.ExecuteActionFilterAsync>b__0(HttpResponseMessage response)\r\n   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskHelpersExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass41`2.<Then>b__40(Task`1 t)\r\n   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskHelpersExtensions.ThenImpl[TTask,TOuterResult](TTask task, Func`2 continuation, CancellationToken cancellationToken, Boolean runSynchronously)"
}
```

**With Pessoa class**

```
[Queryable]
public IQueryable<Pessoa> get()
{
    return _repositorio.Query<Pessoa>();
}


{
    "$id": "1",
    "Message": "An error has occurred.",
    "ExceptionMessage": "An item with the same key has already been added.",
    "ExceptionType": "System.ArgumentException",
    "StackTrace": "   at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentException(ExceptionResource resource)\r\n   at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.Insert(TKey key, TValue value, Boolean add)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.OData.Builder.EdmTypeBuilder.<GetEdmTypes>d__0.MoveNext()\r\n   at System.Linq.Enumerable.<OfTypeIterator>d__aa`1.MoveNext()\r\n   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToDictionary[TSource,TKey,TElement](IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 keySelector, Func`2 elementSelector, IEqualityComparer`1 comparer)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.OData.Builder.EdmModelHelperMethods.BuildEdmModel(String containerNamespace, String containerName, IEnumerable`1 entityTypeConfigurations, IEnumerable`1 entitySetConfigurations)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.OData.Builder.ODataModelBuilder.GetEdmModel()\r\n   at System.Web.Http.OData.Builder.ODataConventionModelBuilder.GetEdmModel()\r\n   at System.Web.Http.HttpActionDescriptorExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass1.<GetEdmModel>b__0(Object _)\r\n   at System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary`2.GetOrAdd(TKey key, Func`2 valueFactory)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.HttpActionDescriptorExtensions.GetEdmModel(HttpActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, Type entityClrType)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.QueryableAttribute.OnActionExecuted(HttpActionExecutedContext actionExecutedContext)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.CallOnActionExecuted(HttpActionContext actionContext, HttpResponseMessage response, Exception exception)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.<>c__DisplayClass2.<System.Web.Http.Filters.IActionFilter.ExecuteActionFilterAsync>b__0(HttpResponseMessage response)\r\n   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskHelpersExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass41`2.<Then>b__40(Task`1 t)\r\n   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskHelpersExtensions.ThenImpl[TTask,TOuterResult](TTask task, Func`2 continuation, CancellationToken cancellationToken, Boolean runSynchronously)"
}
```

Comment: Can you post the Code for `Processo` object?  And one/some of the OData queries you've tried?

Comment: Are you running the release of webapi or an earlier version?  Also,if go to your package management console and type `Get-Package` is `Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.OData  0.1.0-alpha-120815` in the listing?

Comment: Also, if you do 'URL Attempt' #1 ($filter=id eq 1234) is the error message the same as you posted?  The error message you posted looks like you did `api/processos?$id=1` (your model has a capital I btw).

Comment: Same error. but when I try: `/api/processos?$id=1`, the error:   `"Message": "The query parameter '$id' is not supported."`

Comment: I haven't seen this error, and cannot reproduce on my end.  Assuming you're using the oData package that was split of ...it feels like an issue wiring up your child classes.  Asa test can you comment out the ICollections?  Then the virtuals to see if it helps?

Comment: Doing some tests. I observed that only occurs where there is reference to the Person class.
See the edited question.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18170/discussion-between-ebarr-and-riderman-de-sousa-barbosa)

Comment: Could you please try our nightly build to see if it has already been fixed in latest code? Using command in nuget package console: update-package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.OData  -IncludePrerelease -source http://www.myget.org/F/aspnetwebstacknightly/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*This answer is a summary of what transpired in chat.  So it reads a touch different than a standard answer.*

---

I haven't gotten this error specifically, but it seems like OData is having trouble finding an "id" property.  Once oData was pulled out to a standalone package, there were some changes.

**Versions?**
First thing I would check is if you have the stand alone oData package (`Microsoft.Data.OData 5.0.1` and `Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.OData 0.1.0-alpha-120815`).  You can do this by typing `Get-Package` in the package management console.

In chat you posted these:

> Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.OData 0.1.0-alpha-120815
>   Microsoft.Data.Edm 5.1.0-rc2
>   Microsoft.Data.OData 5.1.0-rc2
>   Microsoft.Data.OData.Contrib 5.1.0.50918-rc
>   System.Spatial 5.1.0-rc2

So it looks like you're still running the RC of the product.  There [is an old bug](http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/workitem/344) that seems to describe this behavior.   The short of the bug, is that classes with inherited properties throw errors.

**Current Doesn't Do It**
Updating to the current versions doesn't seem to solve the problem. so the next step is to try the newer signed nightlies.

Instructions to get the signed nightly builds [are here](http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Use%20Nightly%20Builds).

The signed nightly build resolved the problem.

**Another Thought**

After the changes in oData the product needs to be able to identify a key property.  [This article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alexj/archive/2012/08/15/odata-support-in-asp-net-web-api.aspx) states

> Somehow the [Queryable] attribute must find a key property. This
>   happens automatically if your element type has an ID property, if not
>   you might need to manually configure the model (see setting up your
>   model).

If you're using Entity Framework does the person object have an entity key defined?  If not,  can you try the `oDataConventionModelBuilder` as specified in the "setting up your model section".  Something like:

```
ODataModelBuilder modelBuilder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
var pessoa= modelBuilder.EntitySet<Pessoa>("Pessoa"); 

 pessoa..HasKey(p => p.Id); 
 ...
```

Answer (score 0):

OData needs you to specify the concept of a Primary Key for Pessoa class. Either do this by adding an attribute:

```
[DataServiceKey("Id")]
public class Pessoa : IEntity, IAuditable
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    //...
}
```

or by explicitly building your model specifying the key as mentioned in the OData Web API release blog post http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alexj/archive/2012/08/15/odata-support-in-asp-net-web-api.aspx the "Setting up your model" heading section.